# Adaptive Return/Go/New-line button in iOS custom keyboard

Tags: ios, text, keyboard

I am putting together a custom keyboard extension for some practice. I have created a return button on my keyboard. For now, touching the button will simply create a new line. However, I would like to make a button that will change between Return, Go, New-line etc. depending on the circumstances, just like the default iOS keyboard does. 
Any idea as to how one would determine which type of textfield is being typed into, and then change the button function accordingly.

Comment: Typically you set the keyboard's return key type the fields themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each text field you can set the return key type

```
[yourTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
```

There are many types available:

```
UIReturnKeyDefault
UIReturnKeyGo
UIReturnKeyGoogle
UIReturnKeyJoin
UIReturnKeyNext
UIReturnKeyRoute
UIReturnKeySearch
UIReturnKeySend
UIReturnKeyYahoo
UIReturnKeyDone
UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall
```

If you implement UITextFieldDelegate in your class, you can have a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *currentTextField;
```

then store it using the delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentTextField = textfield;
}
```

Then when you press your button on your keyboard, run this:

```
[self.currentTextField setReturnKeyType:newKeyboardType];
```

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you! But I'm having trouble calling the ReturnKey from the button, in the documentation I can only find a declaration for the UIReturnKeyType which only sets/gets the return key type, but how do you actually call it?

Comment: In the delegate methods, you have `textFieldShouldReturn:`.